# Is it possible to set backgroundImage with created image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, background-image, data-uri

I'm looking to set the background of a canvas with an image created with JavaScript rather than with a simple URL.

```
<script>
      var v = document.getElementById("video1");
      var canvas1 = document.getElementById("firstcanvas");
      var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
      var canvas2 = document.getElementById("secondCanvas");
      var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

      var i;
      function draw() {
        ctx1.drawImage(v, 0, 0, 300, 150);
        transform();
      }
      function transform() {
        var dataURL = canvas1.toDataURL("image/png");

        canvas2.style.backgroundImage = dataURL;

      }
      v.addEventListener("play", function() {i = window.setInterval("draw()", 200);}, false);
      v.addEventListener("pause", function() {window.clearInterval(i);}, false);
      v.addEventListener("ended", function() {window.clearInterval(i);}, false);
      </script>
```

Simply put, this code: 1. Continually draws a frame from a video to a canvas using drawImage after which 2. The canvas is converted to an ACTUAL image using dataURL, 3. The image is to be set as the BACKGROUND for the final canvas. The final part, as you might have guessed, doesn't work. I just a working code to set a background image without a URL preferably with the format I presented. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just simply assign the data returned by **.toDataURL()** to the backgroundImage property as it expects it to be wrapped inside **"url()"**.

Here's an example:

```js
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("firstCanvas");
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("secondCanvas");
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

ctx1.beginPath();
ctx1.arc(50, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx1.stroke();

function transform() {
  var dataURL = canvas1.toDataURL("image/png");
  canvas2.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + dataURL + ")";
}
transform();
```

```html
<canvas id="firstCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<canvas id="secondCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Not related to question, but im still curious: do you know how to provide a link to a blob instead of inline base64? I mean `createObjectURL`. And will it work with canvas. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sry for bothering you, was so curious that tested myself) Here it is - https://jsfiddle.net/aqj7c382/. Hella shorter

Comment: Obscure thanks so much. It’s been bugging me and I knew it was something basic that just didn’t know. Works fine, thanks again

Comment: No problem Zodiax - glad I could help!